# fc command somehow mapped to iv

Tags: command-line, bash

I'd like to use the [`fc` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/fc.1posix.html). However when I type `fc` in bash I get

```
Command 'iv' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install openimageio-tools
```

That is weird because I didn't even type `iv`. Furthermore the suggested package seems to be an image processing library which is far from what I want.

What is going on here and how can I use `fc`?

**Edit:**

```
$ type -a fc
fc is a shell builtin

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"

$ bash --version 
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: What is the output of `type -a fc`?

Comment: @dessert Same result as `fc`: Command iv not found.

Comment: @dessert No alias is configured for `fc` by the way.

Comment: Try starting bash without rc file, there's an option for that:  bash --no-rc --no-profile.  Sorry cannot do code highlighting at the moment but you get the idea

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy That helped. Turned out that I had a typo in my `.bashrc`: `EDITOR=iv`. *facepalm*

Comment: @jederik Awesome. Feel free to post a proper  answer documenting this. Answers are far more visible and helpful to people who stumble upon this post in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out I had a typo in my `.bashrc`.

It had

```
EDITOR=iv
```

in it (instead of `EDITOR=vi`), so `fc` tried to edit my last command via the `iv` command. Hence the error message.